# SQL query to get list of customers with group name

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables

**Customer Table**

- CustomerId
- CustomerName

**Groups Table**

- GroupId
- GroupName

**Customer_Group Table**

- CustomerId
- GroupId

A customer may or may not belong to a group. If they belong to any/multiple groups, then an entry is made in the Customer_Group Table. I need an SQL query that will list all the customers along with their group name. If they don't belong to any group then it can show NULL. Otherwise, the group name should be shown as comma separated. For example as below

```
CustomerId   CustomerName   GroupName
1            ABC            NULL 
2            DEF            Sales,Marketing
```

The Customer Table data would be as follows

```
CustomerId  CustomerName   
1           ABC
2           DEF
```

The Group Table data would be as follows

```
GroupId   GroupName
1         Sales
2         Marketing
```

The Customer_Group data would be as follows

```
CustomerId GroupId   
2          1
2          2
```

Please help me with SQL query that will list all the customers along with their group name. I'm using **Microsoft SQL Server 2005**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your're sql queries will be much simpler if you put more time into designing your table structure.  For example, you would have less duplication and one less table by simply adding a groupID column to your customer table and deleting the Customer_Group table altogether.  There are many ways to do it.  No one way is the right way but you can avoid using complicated join statements in your SQL.

Comment: @JasonEnochs that won't work if there is a many-to-many relation between customers and groups, as is suggested by the question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: @Karakuri Yes, it would work just fine.  Your group ID would be a single number(set of flags).  Using one column, you could have almost limitless groups (his group IDs are already simple integers!).  You write one or two simple lines of easy to read code that encodes/decodes your groups and avoid the monster SQL statement like the one below.  Like I said, there are many ways to do it.  I'm a developer, not a DBA so maybe I'm biased in favor of simple, human readable code vs complicated SQL.

Comment: @strawberry  What's wrong is writing an SQL statement like the one below to query something so trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be Something like this

```
SELECT C.CustomerId, C.CustomerName,
       GroupName = STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + GI.GroupName FROM [Group] AS GI           
           INNER JOIN Customer_Group AS CGI ON CGI.GroupId = GI.GroupId
           WHERE CGI.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
           FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Customer C LEFT JOIN Customer_Group CG ON C.CustomerId = CG.CustomerId
GROUP BY C.CustomerId, C.CustomerName
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b12bf/10)**

---

Output would be

```
CustomerId   CustomerName   GroupName
+------------------------------------+
1            ABC            NULL 
2            DEF            Sales,Marketing
```

Comment: Hi @vignesh-kumar I tried this query, the Group names show as comma seperated. However, the result shown is wrong. It shows the Groups for all Customers even if the Customer does not belong to any Group

Comment: @Frenz Check this fiddle. it's working fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f81bb/1. I think you dint test my updated query